# Tabularx in twocolumn documents

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am trying to create a `tabular` that should

1. stretch to the full width of a *single column* of a `twocolumn` document using `X` column specifications and
2. be broken over the columns and pages of a `twocolumn` document.

I have tried the following packages so far, but none could meet both of my requirements:

- vanilla `tabular` environment: none of the requirements are supported
- `tabularx`: supports 1. only
- `longtable`: cannot be used in `twocolumn` mode
- `supertabular`: supports 2. only
- `xtab`: despite the name supports 2. only
- `ltablex`: depends on `longtable` for 2. so it cannot be used in `twocolumn` mode for achieving 2.
- `xltabular`: same shortcoming as `ltablex`
- `tabu`: supports 1., but `longtabu` depends on `longtable`, so it cannot be used in `twocolumn` mode for achieving 2.

*Is there any package or other solution that could support both 1. and 2.?*

Comment: you can use supertabular and fix the column widths, that is usually preferable to using tabularx in any case. You know the page column width and how many table columsn you want so just assign suitable widths to p{..} or array package wc{...} columns.

Comment: I don't know the column widths in advance, unfortunately. The first column's width should be adjusted to the width of the contents, while the second column should fill the rest of the line width. I am using this environment (currently based on tabu, but with no column/page breaking, obviously) in many places in my document (to present pieces of a pretty large ENBF-like grammar), and manually speficying the width of the first column every time would be rather cumbersome.

Comment: Try using `xltabular`  nested in the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package; this environment interrupts the two-column mode to enable inserting page-wide contents.

Comment: @Bernard I'd prefer to keep my tables in two-column mode, but thanks for the idea!

Comment: I had understood you wanted to stretch your table full width?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that I'd like to stretch the table to the full width of a _single column_ of my document. I'll edit my question accordingly, as my wording is indeed confusing.

Comment: do you need line breaking within the column or can you simply use two l column, stretched to full width? in the latter case you can use longtable or supertabular

Comment: I need line breaking in the second column. But technically, I could measure the max width of the first column, and the set the width of the second `p{...}` column based on that. Right now, I'm trying to implement that solution with expl3 by parsing the contents of my table and extracting the first columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package is what you want:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Long Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {lXX}, hlines,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
}
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kapp  & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\end{longtblr}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

[image]